# gnome-terminal - color palette

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to assign color palette on my gnome-terminal but it doesn't change at all... any clue?

Screenshot:

[image]

Aditional info:

- Fedora 18 64bits (shiny new)
- GNOME Terminal 3.6.1
- $XTERM set to xterm-256color
- I tried with new profiles, even with new accounts... same

Comment: Have you tried opening a new terminal after making changes?

Comment: yes, . .bashrc and even rebooting the machine

Comment: Minor correction, I think you mean $TERM set to xterm-256color.  You shouldn't need to restart or reboot anything -- for me with the same setup the colours change straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora configures `ls` to use entries of the 256-color palette if your `$TERM` is set accordingly; see your `$LS_COLORS` variable and the `/etc/DIR_COLORS*` files. On gnome-terminal's UI you can only configure the first 16 of these.

That is, probably the blue and green colors your `ls` produces are simply not the "standard" blue/green colors, but one of the "extended" ones.

Answer (score 0):

In fedora 19 I solved the problem by un-checking the "use colors from system theme" checkbox in the edit/profile preferences/colors pannel.